Deformed completion of negatively curved metric
Suppose X,g is a complete
negative sectional curvature Riemannian manifold. And $C \subset X$ is
compact submanifold.
What are the minimal conditions on $C$ so that
we can deform g on the restriction to $X-C$ to
a complete negatively curved metric on $X-C$.
The comments give one important obstruction, in that $C$ should have codimension 2.

If $X$ is the hyperbolic $n$-space with $n>2$ and $C$ is a point, then then $X-C$ is not aspherical, so has no complete negatively curved metric (by Cartan-Hadamard).

You should assume that $C$ has codimension 2.

Even if $C$ has codimension 2, I am not aware of any such deformation.

@IgorBelegradek: apart from the constant curvature case.

@MoisheKohan: the OP makes no assumption about $C$. Say, what if $C$ is a codimension 2 sphere? If the curvature is constant near $C$, and $C$ is totally geodesic of codimension 2, the deformation exists and is quite straightforward. There are similar (less straightforward) results when $X$ is locally symmetric and $C$ is totally geodesic of codimension 2; in this case the normal bundle of $C$ won't be trivial, but this is irrelevant. For the most difficult case see https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.01974 which has references to easier cases.

I was only thinking about totally geodesic submanifolds.

Please edit your question so that it doesmake sense.

@Igor Belegradek
Can one use this kind of construction to show that
$(\mathbb{R} ^{2} - {0}) \times \Sigma$, for $\Sigma
$ a compact negatively curved Riemann surface has negative
sectional curvature metric?

@Yasha: I don't think this kind of construction is known. The only cases I know is when you remove a totally geodesic compact surface from a locally symmetric negatively curved 4-manifold, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.01974, https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.5001,  https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.2324.  The case when you remove a compact totally geodesic surface from an arbitrary negative curved $4$-manifold is open (to my knowledge).
